# Sum of the elements of a sequence of integers: loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop

Tags: dafny

After reading Getting Started with Dafny: A Guide, I decided to create my first program: given a sequence of integers, compute the sum of its elements. However, I am having a hard time in getting Dafny to verify the program.

```
function G(a: seq<int>): int
  decreases |a|
{
  if |a| == 0 then 0 else a[0] + G(a[1..])
}

method sum(a: seq<int>) returns (r: int)
  ensures r == G(a)
{
  r := 0;
  var i: int := 0;
  while i < |a|
    invariant 0 <= i <= |a|
    invariant r == G(a[0..i])
  {
    r := r + a[i];
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

I get

```
stdin.dfy(12,2): Error BP5003: A postcondition might not hold on this return path.
stdin.dfy(8,12): Related location: This is the postcondition that might not hold.
stdin.dfy(14,16): Error BP5005: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.
```

I suspect that Dafny needs some "help" in order to verify the program (lemmas maybe?) but I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/dDt4) is a version of your program that verifies.

There were two things to fix: the proof that the postcondition follows after the loop, and the proof that the loop invariant is preserved.

### The postcondition

Dafny needs a hint that it might be helpful to try to prove `a == a[..|a|]`. Asserting that equality is enough to finish this part of the proof: Dafny automatically proves the equality and uses it to prove the postcondition from the loop invariant.

This is a common pattern. You can try to see what is bothering Dafny by doing the proof "by hand" in Dafny by making various assertions that you would use to prove it to yourself on paper.

### The loop invariant

This one is a bit more complicated. We need to show that updating `r` and incrementing `i` preserves `r == G(a[..i])`. To do this, I used a `calc` statement, which let's one prove an equality via a sequence of intermediate steps. (It is always possible to prove such things without `calc`, if you prefer, by asserting all the relevant equalities as well as any assertions inside the `calc`. But I think `calc` is nicer.)

I placed the `calc` statement before the updates to `r` and `i` occur. I know that after the updates occur, I will need to prove `r == G(a[..i])` for the updated values of `r` and `i`. Thus, before the updates occur, it suffices to prove `r + a[i] == G(a[..i+1])` for the un-updated values. My `calc` statement starts with `r + a[i]` and works toward `G(a[..i+1])`.

First, by the loop invariant on entry to the loop, we know that `r == G(a[i])` for the current values.

Next, we want to bring the `a[i]` inside the `G`. This fact is not entirely trivial, so we need a lemma. I chose to prove something slightly more general than necessary, which is that `G(a + b) == G(a) + G(b)` for any integer sequences `a` and `b`. I call this lemma `G_append`. Its proof is discussed below. For now, we just use it to get bring the `a[i]` inside as a singleton sequence.

The last step in this `calc` is to combine `a[0..i] + [a[i]]` into `a[0..i+1]`. This is another sequence extensionality fact, and thus needs to be asserted explicitly.

That completes the `calc`, which proves the invariant is preserved.

#### The lemma

The proof of `G_append` proceeds by induction on `a`. The base case where `a == []` is handled automatically. In the inductive case, we need to show `G(a + b) == G(a) + G(b)`, assuming the induction hypothesis for any subsequences of `a`. I use another `calc` statement for this.

Beginning with `G(a + b)`, we first expand the definition of `G`. Next, we note that `(a + b)[0] == a[0]` since `a != []`. Similarly, we have that `(a + b)[1..] == a[1..] + b`, but since this is another sequence extensionality fact, it must be explicitly asserted. Finally, we can use the induction hypothesis (automatically invoked by Dafny) to show that `G(a[1..] + b) == G(a[1..]) + G(b)`.